# Blur top bar to UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, ios7, navigationbar

I made a "single view" app with a UIView interface in a .xib file. I added a navigation bar at the top with some buttons on it and all worked fine in iOS 6.
With Xcode 5 my navigation bar is too short and buttons overlapped status bar. I tried to add a "top bar" in the "Simulated Metrics" panel but once I run the app the bar does not appear (even if it appears in the .xib file during editing).

Same problem when I tried a tool bar because I need a 64 pixel (instead 44) high blur bar.
Does a simple solution to this problem exist? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simulated metrics, while editing a storyboard and/or xib are, are there for you to use when stubbing out your design.  They will not show up at run time.  Think of them as fictional representations or a prototype of what you would like to see in your design without actually having to implement it yet.

IE:  You're not sure if you want a UINavigationBar in your design.  You can layout your design with the UINavigationBar turned on in the simulated metrics and it'll show you what it looks like, but only in the editor not actual run time, and from there you can make your decision on whether or not to keep it or rearrange your other controls.  Something like this is very handy if you create your UINavigationBar programmatically (like I do).  If I simulate the UINavigationBar (even though I'll create it programmatically) then I can get a much better idea of where to layout all my other controls that I DO setup in IB.

All that being said, if you layout all your xib's and SB's in the interface builder then the simulated metrics really is worthless to you for the most part because you can obviously just drag and drop the control onto your xib.

Hope this helps!